# Create a custom email template in python

Tags: python, html, html-table

I need to create a email template in Python to send mail in smtp().
And i need the template to be in the below format, will that be possible ?

[image]

I got this template from python org and i am not sure how to scale it up to something like in the image.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
          table {
            background: white;
            border-radius:3px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            height: auto;
            max-width: 900px;
            padding:5px;
            width: 100%;
            animation: float 5s infinite;
          }
          th {
            color:#FFFFFF;;
            background:#1976d2;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding:10px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
          }
          tr {
            border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
            border-left: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
            color:#666B85;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:normal;
          }
          tr:hover td {
            background:#0000FF;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
          }
          td {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            padding:10px;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:middle;
            font-weight:300;
            font-size:13px;
            border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        Dear Somebody,<br> <br>
        Bla-bla-bla<br><br>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid #1b1e24;">
              <th>Ticket ID</th>
              <th>head2</th>
              <th>head3</th>
              <th>head4</th>
              <th>head5</th>
              <th>head6</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        Bla-bla.<br>
        For more assistance please contact our support team:
        <a href='mailto:some_email@gmail.com'>some_email@gmail.com</a>.<br> <br>
        Thank you!
      </body>
    </html>
    """



    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(HTML, 'html')])
    message['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    message['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    message['To'] = RECEIVER_EMAIL
```

Basically having the skeleton is enough with header and rows.

Anyhelp is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can define a tpl use jinja2, refer https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/ for more details.